# Converting set of points to polygon using C#?

Tags: polygon, c#, point, sql-server, geometry

I want to convert a set of gps ponints to polygon.I used a simple loop to convert it to a WKT and than used makevalid() in sql server and save it in a gemetry column in databasae.Is this way right?or I missed something.
for example I have this points

```
<x1,y1>,<x2,y2>,<x3,y3>,<x4,y4>
```

I used a loop to creat a string like

```
Geometry::STFromText('Polygon(x1 y1,x2 y2,x3 y3,x4 y4,x1 y1)',4326).Makevalid()
```

Is this method right?Do I need any convertin on points .

Comment: For me the method looks OK if your GPS points are in right order. Survey points not always are because surveyor walks as little as possible. Because you have seen good to use MakeValid I guess you may have continuously recorded points and want to remove self-intersections. I do not know how to do it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are building these in C#, the best way is probably to use the SQLGeography/SQLGeometry builder classes.

These can be accessed from the [Microsoft.SqlServer.Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types(v=sql.110).aspx) library.  Some examples of it's use are [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160105073221/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/davidlean/archive/2008/10/30/sql-2008-spatial-samples-part-n-5-of-n-sql-builder-api.aspx).

Since you are using GPS points, they are likely to be Lat/Lons.  In that case I would use Geography datatype rather than Geometry.
If you need to reproject the coordinates this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13447/how-to-reproject-spatial-data-using-free-libraries) may help.  Also this [site](http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/) may provide some help

If you do use Geography then make sure that you polygon is built in a anticlockwise direction.  In SQL Server 2008 you will get an error.  In SQL Server 2012+ you will end up with a large polygon (whole earth) with a small hole.

Comment: Can't MakeValid in SQL Server correct the ring orientation? A polygon built up from one inner ring feels invalid to me so why not to reverse it automatically? Or does MakeValid handle the case only when it deals with "geometry", not "geography"?

Comment: Thanks but If I use geography it will require 2012or above veriosn of this assembely but I should work with 2008 version:(

Comment: On 2012+ geographies both directions are correct.  With 2008 it may convert.  Unfortunately I can't test that right now.  With geometries I don't think it cares, but it may change the direction.  I think this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edkatibah/archive/2008/08/19/working-with-invalid-data-and-the-sql-server-2008-geography-data-type-part-1b.aspx confirms what I have said

Comment: @Majid Geographies are available in 2008, but you can still use geometries with Lat/Lons, but it can cause some issues.

Comment: @MickyT I searched and found that makevalid() for geography is in 2012 and above so I can not use it to make my polygons valid.Can you say which issues I may face?

Comment: @Majid Sorry about that, though makevalid was on 2008.  If you use lat/lons in geometries, functions like STDistance, STLength and others will not give sensible results.  You could build the geometry, makevalid then convert it to a geography.  The link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edkatibah/archive/2008/08/19/working-with-invalid-data-and-the-sql-server-2008-geography-data-type-part-1b.aspx from above shows a method to do this that could be done in c#

Comment: @MickyT Does the WKT that I get from geometry field differs from what I get from geography?I will calculate this parameters using Dotspatial liberary

Comment: @Majid The WKT should not differ between them